# PptxGenJS передача файла в обработчик PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Доброго времени суток.

Существует замечательная библиотека – [PptxGenJS](https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS/releases).
С её помощью можно генерировать PowerPoint презентации на лету.

По умолчанию после формирования презентации, она тут же отдаётся в виде файла.

`pptx.writeFile({fileName: "Presentation-name.pptx"});`

Однако моя задача состоит в том, чтобы передать сгенерированный файл в PHP-обработчик, для дальнейшей отправки на почту.

Подскажите, как это сделать?
Я нашёл информацию, что можно создавать blob и виде двоичного кода отправлять в обработчик.
Но я не совсем понимаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать вывод в base64 или бинарные данные ([документация](https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/docs/usage-saving/#write-props-writeprops)).

Для этого необходимо использовать функцию `pptx.write("binarystring")`. Далее, передаете данные на PHP скрипт.

Со стороны JS код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
pptx.write("binarystring")
  .then((data) => {
    const formData = {
      pptx: {
        value: data,
        options: {
          filename: 'Presentation-name.pptx',
          contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'
        }
      }
    };

  request.post({url:'/up.php', formData: formData});
```

Со стороны PHP, если требуется сохранить файл в систему то:

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['pptx']['tmp_name']);
file_put_contents($_FILES['pptx']['name'], $data);
```

В переменной `$data` будут бинарные данные презентации.